# Style not works with Application Commands

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, command

I have MenuItem List and using the ApplicationCommnds like cut,copy,paste.I want to do some thing when Command is disable.But style not working on it.Default behaviour of ApplicationCommand is ii automatically set the foregroud grey if it disable.But it not working in my case.So i explicitly try to set it.

```
<TextBox x:Name="AssignmentTextBox" >
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Background="White">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" Style="StaticResource _MenuItem}"/>                                 
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"   Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem}"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"  Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem}" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"  Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem}"/>                                    
            <Separator  />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll"  Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: What does the style declaration look like?

Comment: Where the style _MenuItem is defined? In Application Resource? or Somewhere?

Comment: What "some thing" you want to do? Style change of menutiem or other item, code trigger, what kind?

Comment: Actually If any text not selected that time Copy,Cut command should be disable.Its disable but it not looks visually disable.When we move cursor on it that time it not selected but its color remain same.I want when it disable its color should be different.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. You missed a bracket **{** while setting value of Style property for the first MenuItem.

**What is Wrong**

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" Style="StaticResource _MenuItem}"/>
```

**What is right**

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem}"/>
```

[Edited] **In the test case below the enabled MenuItems will be Green and disabled MenuItems will be Red. Hope this will help to you solve your issue**

```
<ContextMenu Background="White">
       <ContextMenu.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="_MenuItem1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="false">
                              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
      </ContextMenu.Resources>
      <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem1}"/>
      <Separator />
      <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"   Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem1}"/>
      <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"  Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem1}" />
      <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"  Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem1}"/>
      <Separator  />
      <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll"  Style="{StaticResource _MenuItem1}"/>
  </ContextMenu>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Somnath - As per the code All MenuItem Forground should be red.But it still black.That is my problem.

Comment: @user1939423 I have updated the answer according to your need. Lets think the enabled MenuItems will be Green and disabled MenuItems will be Red. I have updated the answer. You also can follow the example provided by "iltzortz". Hope this will help to you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you had changed the MenuItem template or override the foreground so that the CommandCan execute cannot update the right visual element to render as "disabled" which should be grey color.

So I wonder if you could show us the template or your style with key _MenuItem, maybe we can tell what is wrong in your case.